# How to put correctly images in a wordpress plugin to show in the frontend, located in a specific plugin folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I need to link an image in my plugin to show in the frontend. So all thread I read tell about use of plugin_dir_url function [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/)

I put my images in a plugin folder called "icone", so if I insert this code images are not found, because plugin search in a folder out of the plugin.

```
echo '<img src="icone/area-di-produzione.png" />'
```

I tried to use this code below but not works, It only stamp the path of the image without showing it (the path stamped is incorrect).. any suggestion?

```
echo '<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'icone/area-di-produzione.png'; ?>" />'
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9OF6.png)

Answer (score 0):

try the code below

```
<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'icone/area-di-produzione.png'; ?>" />
```

Comment: nope.... what I'm doing wrong? writing your code without echo function it broke my site.. so I tried this code but somethings wrong... `<?php if (get_field('produttore')) { echo "<img src='<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'icone/area-di-produzione.png';?>'  />"; }  ?>`